# How to add link(url) to SharePoint site's Document Library via REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

Here what I tried:

[image]

Sending post request to create a link on a document library with bearer token and some data in a body.

Response:

[image]

Comment: It seems the answer given here works the best so far: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162445/is-it-possible-to-create-a-link-to-a-document-with-rest-or-jsom

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online, we can easy achieve it using PnP powershell.

```
$siteurl="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz" 
$libraryTitle="DL"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl
$linkText ="[InternetShortcut]URL=https://www.bing.com"

$memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$writeStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $memStream
$writeStream.WriteLine($linkText)

Add-PnPFile -FileName "Bing.url" -Folder $libraryTitle -Stream $memStream -Values @{_ShortcutUrl="https://www.bing.com"}
```

Comment: any way to do using REST API?

Comment: It seems not a REST API to achieve it, we have to use PnP powershell, or create a custom web API to REST API with CSOM C#.